# Modify value in a Crystal Reports number field based on value in another field

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create a conditional formula that will change the PP.POSPAY_SALARY_MIN column in my report, based on the value of another column.  So here is the logic I am trying to duplicate, so far with errors. The Salary min values are coming in as an internally formatted string of numbers, no decimal points.

```
   select <these are among the many columns in my report>
      ....
      P.POS_HRLY_OR_SLRY,
      PP.POSPAY_SALARY_MIN, 
      ....
```

I want PP.POSPAY_SALARY_MIN to be multiplied by .0001 if P.POS_HRLY_OR_SLRY = 'S' else multiply PP.POSPAY_SALARY_MIN by .01.

Can I do this, and if so, what am I missing in the way I am formatting the formula?

Answer (score 1):

### general suggestion

It's often easier to write condintional calculations as calculated fields instead of writing them inside your SQL statements.

---

### step by step guide:

1. Make the field explorer visible, by either using the icon in the tool bar or the menu "View -> Field Explorer"

[image: show field explorer]

2. Look up the entry for formula fields with the ***fx*** symbol and right-click to open the context menu. Choose "New..."

[image: open context menu and choose new...]

3. The formula editor will open and you can use the crystal report programming language to create your conditional value

[image: formula editor]

4. You can drag and drop the formula field from the field explorer in the same way to your report as you can do it with the database fields.

---

I apologize for the German screen shots. I have no English Crystal Report installation available. Maybe some captions will vary from my translations of the terms.